# Why doesn't GWT let us add key event handlers on document element?

Tags: events, gwt, keyboard-events

I know there's `FocusPanel` on which I can attach such handlers, but in my experience this component does not behave that well. So I'd like to avoid it as much as possible.

So I'm wondering why there's no way to attach key handlers on document too? According to [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html) it works cross-browser, so this shouldn't be a concern.

I've also tried writing some JSNI code to do this myself, which works ok for most cases. However, if there's any other widget that listens for the same event as me on document, and that widget lets the event propagate, I can do pretty much nothing with the event that reached the document, because it's marked as dead and an exception will be thrown whenever I try to access data on that event.

Here's my code so far:

```
public class RichDocument implements HasKeyPressHandlers, HasKeyDownHandlers,
    HasKeyUpHandlers, HasClickHandlers {

  private static final RichDocument instance = new RichDocument();

  public static RichDocument get() {
    return instance;
  }

  private final EventBus eventBus = new SimpleEventBus();

  private RichDocument() {
    startListening();
  }

  @Override
  public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
    return eventBus.addHandler(ClickEvent.getType(), handler);
  }

  @Override
  public HandlerRegistration addKeyDownHandler(KeyDownHandler handler) {
    return eventBus.addHandler(KeyDownEvent.getType(), handler);
  }

  @Override
  public HandlerRegistration addKeyPressHandler(KeyPressHandler handler) {
    return eventBus.addHandler(KeyPressEvent.getType(), handler);
  }

  @Override
  public HandlerRegistration addKeyUpHandler(KeyUpHandler handler) {
    return eventBus.addHandler(KeyUpEvent.getType(), handler);
  }

  @Override
  public void fireEvent(GwtEvent<?> event) {
    eventBus.fireEvent(event);
  }

  private native void startListening()/*-{
    var self = this;

    var fire = function (event) {
      event = event || $wnd.event;
      @com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent::fireNativeEvent(Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/NativeEvent;Lcom/google/gwt/event/shared/HasHandlers;)(event, self);
    };

    if ($wnd.document.addEventListener) {
      $wnd.document.addEventListener("click", fire, false);
      $wnd.document.addEventListener("keydown", fire, false);
      $wnd.document.addEventListener("keypress", fire, false);
      $wnd.document.addEventListener("keyup", fire, false);
    } else {
      $wnd.document.attachEvent("onclick", fire);
      $wnd.document.attachEvent("onkeydown", fire);
      $wnd.document.attachEvent("onkeypress", fire);
      $wnd.document.attachEvent("onkeyup", fire);
    }
  }-*/;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to want to add to the document instead of using `Event.addNativePreviewHandler()`?

Comment: Note that `addNativePreviewHandler` acts in the capture phase (emulated in IE), while "attaching to the document" would be in the bubbling phase. This can make a difference. Depends on your needs.

Comment: @HilbrandBouwkamp, @ThomasBroyer addNativePreviewHandler seems to work, but how would I transform that event to a proper `KeyUpEvent`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about the following?

```
RootPanel.get().addDomHandler(handler, KeyDownEvent.getType());
```

It adds them on the document's body, but that's not much different.

Comment: It is different in the way that the document always occupies the whole viewport, while the body element not necessarily. For example if body has CSS `width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 200px auto;`, the body area is really small. Just an example.

Comment: That's why I said "not much different" and not "the same". It's relatively easy to get the `body` occupy the whole viewport though. I believe there's some kind of hackery that would make it possible to register at the document though, without even touching JSNI (using `Document.get().<Element>cast()`, `DOM.setEventListener` and `DOM.sinkEvents`).

Comment: yes, it seems it could work, but how would I transform that event into a KeyUpEvent, or similar.

Comment: `DomEvent.fireNativeEvent`, where you can pass any `HasKeyUpHandlers`, or your own implementation of `HasHandlers`, or simply use a `HandlerManager` where you'd have previously registered your `HasKeyUpHandlers` (as within widgets).