# GWT enable esc key for all my web application

Tags: java, gwt, keyboard

I need to add a function when i press esc key in each panel of my web application. Specifically when i press esc key in my web application i need to show a panel which alert if is need to exit from the web application.

my question is : how can do to enable esc key shortcut ?

Answer (score 2):

In GWT, you generally implement global shortcuts using a [`NativePreviewHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.html#addNativePreviewHandler%28com.google.gwt.user.client.Event.NativePreviewHandler%29).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet from a project I work on, it should give you an idea of what to do:

```
public class MyDialogBox extends com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox 
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreviewNativeEvent(Event.NativePreviewEvent event)
    {
        super.onPreviewNativeEvent(event);
        switch (event.getTypeInt())
        {
            case Event.ONKEYDOWN:
                if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ESCAPE) 
                {
                    // do stuff
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this run when i select a dialog box but i need to run it when i press in each moment esc key without select a particular gwt object

Comment: As I wrote, this is a pointer in the right direction. See @Thomas Broyer's post also and another by him: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737808/why-doesnt-gwt-let-us-add-key-event-handlers-on-document-element